# What does this warning mean when running a vaadin web app in IntelliJ IDEA - no startup urls

Tags: java, intellij-idea, vaadin

I am able to run a vaadin app and development mode task starts,
and this warning is displayed:

```
[WARN] No startup URLs supplied and no plausible ones found -- use -startupUrl
```

I can not find any information about this warning and what it means.  IntelliJ idea is not launching my selected web browser, and I suspect that this warning is the reason why, but I don't know how to follow the above directions, because I don't even know what is telling me this, and where in the Idea project I might add the `-startupUrl` parameter.

My problem is that although the development mode task starts when I run my project, I cannot seem to locate some url (`http://localhost:8000` or whatever) that my app is loadable from.

The full output when I run my app is:

```
  /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx256m -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 12.app/bin" ....
  [WARN] No startup URLs supplied and no plausible ones found -- use -startupUrl
  Dev Mode initialized
```